# How to import Intellij IDEA keymaps into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have so many reasons to use Intellij IDEA instead of eclipse, but now I have to use eclipse in my team.So as we all know, Intellij IDEA's keymaps is very very convenient and it even supports eclipse's keymaps.Is there any tools or plugin that is able to import Intellij IDEA's keymaps into eclipse?

Comment: Get your team to change tool. If they don't listen, threaten to buy licensed copies of IntelliJ for the whole team yourself. Failing that, change job.

Comment: Just curious, why do you have to use Eclipse?

Comment: The story of so many developers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try IdeaKeyScheme plugin, should work in latest Eclipse

http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/intellij_idea_key_scheme_for

Comment: For me it didn't work. I have Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2. I've took that jars from the google repository - btw, the above link is broken (website is not responding) - and I've placed them under eclipse/plugins. I am on an Oracle Linux 7 virtually provisioned. Maybe I do have some admin restrictions but I don't think so. Does anybody have this problem too?

Comment: Your link is dead bro.. @Mikalai Daronin

Answer (score 2):

Answering again as this thread is not up to date.

I've used that plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/intellij-idea-keymap-eclipse and it establishes default idea's keymap to me just fine.